# Parse same JSON String Multiple Times in python

Tags: python, json

I need to parse the following json output, so I can take parse the Title entries

```
[{"Title":"000webhost","Name":"000webhost","Domain":"000webhost.com","BreachDate":"2015-03-01","AddedDate":"2015-10-26T23:35:45Z","ModifiedDate":"2015-10-26T23:35:45Z","PwnCount":13545468,"Description":"In approximately March 2015, the free web hosting provider <a href=\"http://www.troyhunt.com/2015/10/breaches-traders-plain-text-passwords.html\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">000webhost suffered a major data breach</a> that exposed over 13 million customer records. The data was sold and traded before 000webhost was alerted in October. The breach included names, email addresses and plain text passwords.","DataClasses":["Email addresses","IP addresses","Names","Passwords"],"IsVerified":true,"IsFabricated":false,"IsSensitive":false,"IsActive":true,"IsRetired":false,"IsSpamList":false,"LogoType":"png"},{"Title":"Lifeboat","Name":"Lifeboat","Domain":"lbsg.net","BreachDate":"2016-01-01","AddedDate":"2016-04-25T21:51:50Z","ModifiedDate":"2016-04-25T21:51:50Z","PwnCount":7089395,"Description":"In January 2016, the Minecraft community known as Lifeboat <a href=\"https://motherboard.vice.com/read/another-day-another-hack-7-million-emails-and-hashed-passwords-for-minecraft\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">was hacked and more than 7 million accounts leaked</a>. Lifeboat knew of the incident for three months before the breach was made public but elected not to advise customers. The leaked data included usernames, email addresses and passwords stored as straight MD5 hashes.","DataClasses":["Email addresses","Passwords","Usernames"],"IsVerified":true,"IsFabricated":false,"IsSensitive":false,"IsActive":true,"IsRetired":false,"IsSpamList":false,"LogoType":"svg"}]
```

To parse, this I use the following code :

```
cat $myfile | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)[0]['Title']"
```

But this results in the output :

> 000webhost

whereas I need the output to be :

> 000webhost
>
> Lifeboat

Comment: why should the output be that ?

Comment: @JoshHamet They already posted that.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a command line rather than using a proper script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should be doing this with a proper script. Also, that's a superfluous use of `cat`, and you should put Bash parameter expansions inside double-quotes to prevent word-splitting. You can omit the quotes if you're sure the path doesn't contain spaces, but it's really not a good habit to get into.

Anyway, this code works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
python -c "import sys,json;print('\n'.join([u['Title']for u in json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))]))" "$myfile"
```

**output**

```
000webhost
Lifeboat
```

---

Here's how to write it as a proper script.

```
import sys
import json

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print('\n'.join([u['Title'] for u in data]))
```

Comment: I know I should do it with a proper script, but this is for a bash program

Comment: @NavanChauhan Fair enough. I recommend you use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to make your Bash scripts more robust. And you may find the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) useful.

Comment: What change should I bring in it, so it parses only the top 3 out of numerous results ?

Comment: @NavanChauhan A simple way to do that is to slice the list returned by `json.load`, eg `print('\n'.join([u['Title']for u in json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))[:3]]))`.

Comment: Thanks a ton mate

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display all the titles you need to loop over the items in the array. Currently you're asking for the first item `[0]`.

You can do this as a one-liner using a comprehension to extract the titles:

```
[item['Title'] for item in json.load(sys.stdin)]
```

And then a loop to print out each title on a separate line:

```
for title in [item['Title'] for item in json.load(sys.stdin)]: print title
```

So the complete command line script would be:

```
cat $myfile | python -c "import sys, json; for title in [item['Title'] for item in json.load(sys.stdin)]: print title"
```

Comment: @NavanChauhan How can help you if you don't tell me what the syntax error is?